# Accessing Lotus Notes 'localhost' URL over wireless connection from mobile device

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I have Lotus Notes (with Domino Designer and Administrator) 8.5.3 installed. I create a database locally and run it using `localhost` so my URL looks like - `http://localhost/path/myDatabase.nsf`. It works without any problem.

Now I want to access my locally developed database over wireless connection on my mobile device. I have setup a wireless router and it assigns my PC (on which database resides) IP address, say 192.168.2.3. When I use the URL `http://192.168.2.3/path/myDatabase.nsf` in my browser on PC then it gives me error of `HTTP Web Server: Access Denied Exception`. The same goes if I use the URL from my mobile device. It seems that my mobile device is able to connect to the `localhost` using IP address but my local Lotus Notes server denies access to it if it comes via IP address. Anyone knows how to resolve this problem? Is there a setting which I need to do to make it work or I would require a Domino server to be setup on my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't really be done out of the box in the notes client. First you need a Domino web server on your machine that you can link to. The Notes client does not offer this.

It does have a scaled down web server which is active when you "Preview in Web Browser", but it is very limited and not designed to take external requests from the machine.

One solution to this is to create an eclipse plugin which you have set up as your own server to accept connections. The plugin then hands off to the Notes client for getting data.

It is non-trival though. If you are new to writing plugins I recommend the redbook as a good starting point.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Redbooks%3A+Creating+Plugins+for+Lotus+Notes%2C+Sametime%2C+and+Symphony#action=openDocument&res_title=IBM_Redbooks_Creating_Plugins_for_Lotus_Notes_Sametime_and_Symphony_sitemap&content=pdcontent

Also this set of videos.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Video_Creating_Your_Fist_Eclipse_Plugin_For_Lotus_Notes

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Simon. The Redbook link works but its internal links do not, they give me error of `Error 404 HTTP Web Server: Couldn't find design note - Architectural_Components`. I guess its contents have been moved. And yes I don't know anything about plugin creation. Any ideas what APIs should I refer to via which I would be able to create my own server and then gives data to Lotus Notes as you said?

Comment: updated the URL. Let me know if it works. The Redbook should contain lots of samples to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Will installing a Domino server be an easier solution? I will really have to take a deep look into developing plugin for Eclipse as I am a novice in that area.

Comment: Yep, installing a Domino server would work fine.